# NodeJS/NPM - Package that will merge css files

Tags: node.js, optimization, npm

I'm currently trying to optimize my website and I would like to know if there is a package that would **automatically** **merge** every css file and send **only parts** that are required for the site.

Is there anything similar to my idea?

Comment: gulp is your friend for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably go ahead with Gulp or Grunt , I prefer Gulp and you can follow this way

More details cab be found here https://gulpjs.com/

> Create A Gulp Task
>
> Then Execute the task by referring the name (This would create the merged css in the build/css folder)

```
var less = require('gulp-less');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-csso');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
gulp.task('css', function(){
    return gulp.src('client/css/*.css')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});
```

> `gulp.task('default', [ 'css' ]);`

Comment: Welcome !! Let me know if you struck somewhere